# Defining multiple possibilities for the same element

Tags: xsd

is it possible in XML Schema to define the same element with several different definitions depending on one attribute.

As Example:

```
<xsd:element name="Element">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:attribute name="type" fixed="type1"/>
    <xsd:seqeuence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="Element">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:attribute name="type" fixed="type2"/>
     <xsd:attribute name="value" type="xsd:integer"/>
    <xsd:seqeuence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="RootElement">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element ref="Element"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Or is there any other way to solve this problem.
It is important that both definitions are named "Element", because I have an application needing that both elements are named the same way. But there is a second application that needs the additional information for type2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider removing the `type` attribute and just defining two childnodes with the different structures you wish.

This way you can have

```
<Element>
  <ElementType1>
    <!--whatever-->
  </ElementType1>
</Element>
```

and

```
<Element>
  <ElementType2 value="42">
    <!--whatever-->
  </ElementType1>
</Element>
```

in the same document.

Try this in the DTD section for `Element`:

```
<!ELEMENT Element (ElementType1?)>  <!-- the ? means 1 or 0 -->
<!ELEMENT Element (ElementType2?)>
```

or rather this if only one is ever allowed under `Element` and `Element` is not allowed to be empty:

```
<!ELEMENT Element (ElementType1 | ElementType1)>
```

You can read more on about [DTD element operators](http://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/dtd_element_operators.cfm).

Comment: Wouldn't this mean, that my parser won't read it anymore. I can't change one of the parsers, so this wouldn't be a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If  you're using XML Schema 1.1, you can use [type alternatives](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#tac). For XML Schema 1.0, look into `xsi:type` or an add-on like [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/).